# How To Access webcam device from browser in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am already setting device for camera in my after I am using it in my localhost camera accessed but after trying another to connect the camera from another to my local cannot use this device camera example, my server `172.1.1.10` I can access this camera device from my localhost but after using from another `172.1.1.11` to `172.1.1.10` device camera cannot accessed can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your using secure protocol

```
if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
        .then(function (stream) {
          video.srcObject = stream;
        })
        .catch(function (err0r) {
          console.log("Something went wrong!");
        });
    }
```

or Download Plugin
http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/

Comment: yes thanks for answer my question but i am just using from lan iam not using hosting

Comment: I suggest first test your webcam properly working or not using online tester. here https://www.onlinemictest.com/webcam-test/